# Use jQuery to count the number of div's inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have the following output:

```
<section class="group">
  <div class="header">Header 1</div>
      <div class="item">item1</div>
      <div class="item">item2</div>
      <div class="item">item3</div>
  </div>    
</section>

<section class="group">
  <div class="header">Header 2</div>
      <div class="item">item1</div>
      <div class="item">item2</div>
      <div class="item">item3</div>
      <div class="item">item4</div>
      <div class="item">item5</div>
    </div>   
</section>
```

I want to use jQuery to tell me how many `.item` elements are in each `<section>`. Currently trying this, but it doesn't give me the correct number:

```
$('section.group').each(
  function() {
    alert($(this).length);
  }
);
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but you are trying to count the section.group element - not the child div's. So all you need to do is either use children().length() or as the answer posted. So close! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
$('section.group').each(
  function() {
    alert($('.item', $(this)).length);
  }
);
```

#### [[Working Example]](http://jsbin.com/epiwir)

Or

```
$('section.group').each(
  function() {
    alert(($(this).find('.item')).length);
  }
);
```

#### [[Working Example]](http://jsbin.com/epiwir/2)

---

You were iterating over sections but you were missing to count elements with class `item` :)

---

**Helpful Links:**

- [jQuery Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- [jQuery find() method](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".group").find(".item").length
```

This is the simplest one line solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at '.item' in the context of *this*. *this* has a length of one because this = 'section.group'

```
$('section.group').each(
  function() {
    alert($('.item',this).length);
  }
);​
```

See the **Selector Context** heading here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('section').each(function() {
    alert($('.item', this).length);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aXVqM/

Answer (score 1):

Look the following example.
http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/KMgtZ/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('section.group').each(
  function() {
    alert($(this).children('.item').length);
  }
);
```

this would be faster than the other ones....I suppose

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
$('.change').click(function () {
     var lng = $(".item").length;
            $('.change ').height(function (index, height) {
                return (height * lng);
                //alert(height);
            });

     alert(lng);
        });
```

.change is the class of div which height or width you have t o change
you can check how to implement here : http://jsfiddle.net/sahilosheal/572WV/

Answer (score 0):

I have change the name of second section class name
see demo here:

```
$('section').each(function() {
    var numItems = $('.group').children('div.item').length;

    alert(numItems+''); 
});

$('section').each(function() {
    var numItems = $('.group1').children('div.item').length;

    alert(numItems+''); 
});
```

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salwenikhil0724/N3TBg/).